# Protege 5.2 for creating an ontology

Tags: sparql

I'm using Protege 5.2 right now. The SPARQL tab doesn't seem to work. Like the window for typing the query itself is not opening . Any idea where the mistake is ?  Should I download anything more to do the querying ?

Comment: Try to update Protégé SPARQL Plugin: _File > Check for plugins…_.

Comment: Right, there was a bug in the OWL API. Latest version has fixed this.

Comment: Thus, most likely, also you have to update OWLAPI RDF Library plugin: see https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-query-plugin/issues/10

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot ! Had to install the plugins