# SPARQL Query tab in Protege doesn't show anything

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I open the SPARQL Query tab in Protege but the result is this:

[image]

How can I write my query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971310

Comment: As Stanislav linked to, update the plugins, e.g. RDF 2.0.3

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Ok, cool. The other thread doesn't contain an accepted answer. Maybe you can provide one here and accept your own answer. This might help others.

Comment: what I've to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> It happens in version 2.0.1 of Protégé SPARQL Plugin, bundled with
>   Protege 5.2, after any ontology is loaded.

> Update the the "OWLAPI RDF Library" and "Protege SPARQL Plugin" to the latest version with the auto-update mechanism (which appears when starting up Protege or can be activated through the `File > Check for plugins…` menu):

> [image: autoupdate]

Source: https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-query-plugin/issues/10.

Comment: I checked that the plug-ins are updated and restarted Protégé, and it still doesn't worked. The trick was to write a first SPARQL query (without executing it) *before* loading the ontology.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around is downloading the "**Snap SPARQL Query**" plugin and adding the view on the SPARQL tab.

Answer (score 1):

For Protege 5.5.0, you may also need to add query view from menu:

Window--> View-> Query View->  SPARQL Query

And drop it into the SPARQL Query tab.

Answer (score 0):

try to enlarge the heap size for Protégé.
I have had the same problem for **SPARQL Query** and others. Plugin update never worked for me and each time I just delete the new plugins and Protégé works as If nothing happens.

So the solution I have found till now is to not update plugins but to enlarge heap size.

How to do it?

There is a wiki for Protégé 3 and 4 here: https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Setting_Heap_Size but not for Protégé 5 so I was supposed to figure it myself.

Well, you should just open the **Protege.l4j.ini** file and change the heap size limits from {200,500} to {2000,5000} (I am not sure If your computer will stand that, you must read the wiki above to know more about it).

It should be like this:

```
    -Xms2000M
    -Xmx5000M
    -Xss16M
```

Hope this can help someone there.
Best regards,
AmelieSpark.